# Meta Tags Not Displaying Properly Across Next.js Pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using the Head component in Next.js to add meta tags. I'm using it in _app and other pages, and I've assigned an ID to each meta tag. However, I've noticed that only the _app includes the defined meta data. Consequently, when I paste links to other pages on Facebook posts, only the _app meta data appears. Although the other pages' meta tags are visible in the HTML when inspecting in developer mode. What could be causing this discrepancy?

```
<Head>
    <title key='title'>{metaTag.title}</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no' />
    <meta property='og:image' content={metaTag.thumbnail} key='thumbnail' />
    <meta
      name='description'
      content={metaTag.description}
      key='description'
    />
    <meta property='og:type' content='website' key='og:type' />
    <meta property='og:title' content={metaTag.title} key='og:title' />
    <meta
      property='og:description'
      content={metaTag.description}
      key='og:description'
    />
    <meta
      property='og:site_name'
      content={metaTag.title}
      key='og:site_name'
    />
  </Head>
```